# Backup CF disk data to image

Tags: backup, disk-image

- Is it possible to backup Compact Flash (CF) disk data to an image file and restore later?
- Can you please give some pointers on the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdX of=cf_card.img
```

Restore:

```
$ dd if=cf_card.img of=/dev/sdX
```

Comment: ErikA: 'dd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.   Or: dd: /dev/sdg: No such file or directory   :)

Comment: Hehe. In the case of a question where the OS isn't specified, I just default to linux/BSD. They ought to be using that anyway. :)